# Expanding shine made with bevel and emboss

Tags: adobe-photoshop, button

I have made a shiny button with bevel and emboss. I like how it shines in the corner. Is it possible to extend that shine to the right and down? 
Here are my button and bevel & emboss layer settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want it on the bottom right corner or you want it going down the entire right side?

Comment: Either adjust the Layer Style settings, or draw the white areas you want on a new layer.

Comment: I just wanted to expand that white area a little to the right and bottom.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the light direction setting so it's coming more from the left side instead of the left corner?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the light source more to the side to make the side edge shine. Or to the top for the top edge. Deselect Global Light to be able to use different angles in other instances of the Layer Style. This is similar to how a still life photographer would set his lights.

You can combine a couple of Layer Styles by duplicating your shape layer and blend them with the 'Lighten' mode.

Here i used two. One with your setting and one more on the side.

[image: light settings]

[image: icon]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand it, try and play with the Contours. It usually helps. Open the graph, and adjust it the way you see fit.